# Google Apps Script automatic (on edit) sort (specific sheets only)

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script

I used to have a script for my Sheet, that was based on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7211/how-can-i-make-some-data-on-a-google-spreadsheet-auto-sorting this here to automatically sort a specific sheet whenever it is edited. However, I can't fixate the date though, it seem to have stopped working. I already did some research and apparently the sorting method was changed some while ago.

Now basically the thing I need is the following: I have a google spreadsheet that has a hell lot of different sheets (20+) I used to have only one sheet that needs sorting, but the whole thing has grown over time, and by now it is already two sheets I need sorting, and it is highly likely that the number will increase even further -  and it is crucial, that the sorting only applies to these specific sheets. And to complicate the issue even more, the order of the sheets is not fixated, so I cannot work with sheet IDs, as they are likely to change, so it has to work with the sheet names (which can also change, but it's not very likely - and if it happens, the script is adapted rather quickly).

The Sheets that need sorting contain a lot of data in about 6-7 columns, has a header row and should be sorted by the first column, smallest number on top.

What I came up with as of now is the following:

```
function AutoSortOnEdit(){
  // select active sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // select correct sheet
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("testsheet456");

  // select range (exclude top row)
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:ZZ999");

  // actually do the sorting
  range.sort({column: 1, ascending: true});

 Browser.msgBox("sort done"); 
}
```

The Message box is just there so I see that the thing was  executed, as soon as it works properly, this will be removed. I also added a custom trigger with from spreadsheet on edit.

What is funky is, when I change the range.sort to just "(1, true)" instead of what I have now, it throws an error "method sort(number,boolean) not found"...

But the bad news actually is: with that code up there a) I get no error b) the message box appears, so it actually went through the whole thing, c) it also works when I actually edit that thing (which is good) but d) no sorting whatsoever is done...

So, can anyone help me out with this? I see no real reason why that shouldn't work (but then again, I'm not a programmer, so that's why I came here for help. :P). Additionally, I would then still need - as stated in the introduction - a way to apply that script to two (or more) specific sheets (by name), as it currently is just for one sheet, but I wanted to make it work for one first, and it even fails with this right now....

Thanks in advance,

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your range is invalid. `A2:ZZ999` doesn't work if there are is no cell with address `ZZ999` in your sheet. You can make it work by using `sheet.getLastRow()` and `sheet.getLastColumn()`. To sort several sheets you need an array with all the sheets in it and then loop through that. For example with a forEach loop.

```
function AutoSortOnEdit() {
  var sheetNames = ["testsheet456", "testsheet457", "testsheet458"];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheetNames.forEach(function(name) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
    range.sort({column: 1, ascending: true});
  });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This also works pretty well:

```
function AutoSortOnEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet.getLastColumn());
    ss.sort(1, false);
  });
}
```

Comment: var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("FormResponce");
  sheet.sort(1, false);

Comment: This is also works well:
  
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("FormResponce");
  sheet.sort(1, false);