# Sorting a certain range on Edit()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am  trying to automatically sort a certain range of my sheet `onEdit` in a way that on the top is an empty cell and towards the bottom are the oldest entries.
I have gotten this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583187/google-spreadsheet-script-check-if-edited-cell-is-in-a-specific-range) and tried to modify it for my needs:

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
   if( sheet != ss.getSheetByName('cover sheet'))
   {
      var editRange = { // B4:J6
         top: 29,
         bottom: sheet.getLastRow()+1,
         left: 4,
         right: 11
      };
      // Exit if we're out of range
      var thisRow = e.range.getRow();
      if (thisRow < editRange.top || thisRow > editRange.bottom) return;

      var thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
      if (thisCol < editRange.left || thisCol > editRange.right) return;

      // We're in range; timestamp the edit
      var ss = e.range.getSheet();
      ss.getRange(editRange).sort({column: 1, ascending: true});
   }
}
```

But that does not work. Any Ideas? Here is the link to a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11zVjl19EwZxyYBapo9HXXsrcgxdc4Dnn1tSzdPwXbf4/edit?usp=sharing).

Regards

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Can you provide a sample to show what it does and what it should do?

Comment: It should sort the specific rows in a sheet if the sheet is not the coversheet. It does nothing. I´ll create a sample-spreadsheet

Comment: Try running the function from the code editor with some `Logger.log('some text here: ' + variableName)` statements, then VIEW the LOGS to see what it printed to the logs.  For example.  Put `Logger.log('it ran!')` at the very top of the function, to determine if the function is running or not.  Change the first `if` statement to:  `if( sheet.getName() === 'cover sheet')`

Comment: Did a logger right after on edit(e){ and that didnt prog, so i guess for some reason the script does not automatically trigger. Any idea why? the script is bound to the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

what you need should be something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var thisSS = e.source,
      editedRow = e.range.getRow(),
      editedCol = e.range.getColumn();

  if(editedCol === 4){
    thisSS.sort(editedCol, false);
  }
  thisSS.insertRowBefore(2);
}
```

then paste it to your sheet's script, then go to "Resources >> Current project's triggers" and setup the trigger to run the function "onEdit" when the onEdit Event occour.

best regards.

Comment: Unfortunately i need another solution than insert row, since on the left side of this area is a region that should not be changed.

Comment: Also the sort should not leave the boundaries of the box, but be sorted inside the box.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that there are cells in ranges that you declared. As mentioned by @SpiderPig in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32962477), a range will be invalid if there is no cell within the given range.

For this, you may also try using `bottom: sheet.getLastRow() -1` like the solution given:

```
function AutoSortOnEdit() {
    var sheetNames = ["testsheet456", "testsheet457", "testsheet458"];

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    sheetNames.forEach(function(name) {
        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
        var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
        range.sort({column: 1, ascending: true});
    });
}
```

Hope that works for you. Happy coding!

Comment: I am a little bit worried about the runtime: if i see that right it always sorts all the sheets in that area even if the change wasn´t made in that area. tecnically it would be enough to only sort the sheet that got edited if the edit was in that area or am i wrong?